# Cannot set database config variable from Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

This does not work:

`bin/console doctrine:query:sql "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0" --env=test`

I can execute the SQL part of the command via MySQL Workbench. On the console, it will just give me:

`/var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Util/Debug.php:71:int 0`

Which could possibly be the correct return value as no columns are affected.

But when I do `SELECT @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` it is still set to `1`.

To clarify: I use the same user to perform these operations via console as via MySQL client.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that changing this setting does only apply to the current session, which will be closed directly after the command is executed.